# Is it legal to accept this type of scholarship while on an F-1 visa?

Tags: graduate-school, funding, international-students

So here's my situation: I am a student on F-1 visa who has been offered a scholarship from another university (not the one where I am studying) for a week long workshop in a subject that I research. This scholarship is not classified as employment, and it is just a scholarship / reimbursement money. Is it legal to accept this scholarship?

Comment: Questions about visa compliance should be directed to your university's international student services office.  Don't take advice from internet strangers if your visa is at risk.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite legal and has been done many times. Students attend conferences and get reimbursed for that.